# When can I start the "From Ashes" DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does the From  Ashes DLC mission start?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/where-does-the-from-ashes-dlc-mission-start)

At what point in the story can I begin the *From Ashes* DLC? I don't want to buy it before I can use it, so I want to know, when is the earliest it would be available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you unlock the Normandy and can visit Eden Prime.