# Where does the From  Ashes DLC mission start?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I haven't been able to actually play Mass Effect 3 too much yet and was wondering how to start the *From Ashes* DLC so when I jump back on I can. I've never actually been able to start DLCs on the the previous game. It would help me if someone would point out when and where these extra events occur throughout the game.

Comment: It could be that you are like me and unable to see or start the mission despite having paid the fee and downloaded this content several times. Good luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look for the mission called **Priority: Eden Prime**. Assuming you have the DLC installed, this should be available to you in the game as soon as you board the Normandy and can use your Galaxy Map.

It is, in fact, the first thing I did upon having a choice about where to go.

As a heads up, there is a bonus mission on that planet called **Eden Prime: Resistance Movement**. Make sure you've done everything possible on that before completing the main DLC mission, as [it appears you can not return to Eden Prime later if you missed anything](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53863/3062).

Comment: That's not entirely true, I had already finished the game when I started the DLC and it didn't show up on my mission menu until I had read an email (on my private terminal to the left of the galaxy map) with the same name (Priority: Eden Prime) as the mission. Hope this helps others!