# Is there anything special I have to do to activate the From Ashes DLC, if I install it when I'm halfway through playing the game?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I bought the From Ashes DLC ages ago and have played it through before, but haven't played ME3 for ages and decided to start a new play-through. I started the game without realising that the DLC was not installed, so I installed it halfway through the game. Does that matter? Is there anything I need to do to trigger it, other than Priority Mars which I did ages ago?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the From  Ashes DLC mission start?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/where-does-the-from-ashes-dlc-mission-start)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I found that answer already. When I installed the DLC, I was orbiting Eden Prime. I then saved and hard reset my machine, but still when I go to Eden Prime I can't land, and I have no private messages. I've also gone to the Citadel and returned to Eden Prime, but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I Googled this a lot to no avail and I've now figured it out, so I thought I'd share in case anyone else gets stuck. Basically, problem 1 was that my XBox 1 said "installed" after I selected each individual add-on but, in reality, that just started the install process. It didn't actually finish until about 20 minutes later. No joy after going back to Eden Prime so I saved the game, went back to the main menu so that it could check downloadable content again, and resumed the game.

I was still orbiting Eden Prime while saving, but the mission has now appeared and, therefore, I assume all the others have too if people are just searching for general ME3 DLC advice and wind up here.